# How to use reload item at instead of reloading all the data with firestore

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, uicollectionview

I have a chat app use Firestore, when a new `document or -> (message)`, added to the Firestore my collectionView reload all the data over again and the app freezes for a second until all the data reload, I don't know much about collectionViews but I think if am not wrong this happens because of the collectionView trying to calculate the size for each cell this is the debugger message

```
The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fbd974b3c40>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fbd97930600; frame = (0 61; 414 663); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002c5df20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000023f9640>; contentOffset: {-5, -5}; contentSize: {404, 8}; adjustedContentInset: {5, 5, 5, 5}; layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fbd974b3c40>; dataSource: <DELEVARE___ÿØŸäŸÑŸäŸÅÿ±Ÿä.DriverChat: 0x7fbd97843600>>.
2021-01-16 13:54:43.232052+0200 DELEVARE - ديليفري[51104:999159] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

`symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.`

this debugger message gets called `repeated` with every cell loaded to collectionView, Here is my collectionView [How to solve UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65751634/how-to-solve-uicollectionviewflowlayoutbreakforinvalidsizes)

I don't know how to insert only the new appended item to the array in collectionView, I want this just to react like a normal chat app.

I have tried this

```
func getMessages(){
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        
        let firestore = Firestore.firestore()
        let doc = firestore.collection("طلبات قيد العمل").whereField("driverUid", isEqualTo: uid)
        doc.getDocuments { (query, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            }
            for document in query!.documents{

                let chatDoc = document.reference.collection("المحادثات")

                chatDoc.addSnapshotListener { (querysnap, err) in
                    if err != nil {
                        print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                    }
                    self.messages = []
                    for snap in querysnap!.documents{
                    
                    let data = snap.data()
                    guard let message = data["message"] as? String else {return}
                    guard let senderid = data["senderID"] as? String else {return}
                    guard let timestamp = data["date"] as? Timestamp else {return}
                    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timestamp.seconds))
                    if senderid == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
                        let drivermessages = driverMessages(image: UIImage(), text: message, date: date, isSender: true, driverid: senderid)

                        // this line of code is doing the same as collectionView.reloadData()

                        self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
                            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.comments.count, section: 0)
                            self.messages.append(drivermessages)
                            self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
                        }, completion: nil)
                        
                    }else {
                        
                        guard let message2 = data["message"] as? String else {return}
                        guard let senderid2 = data["senderID"] as? String else {return}
                        guard let timestamp2 = data["date"] as? Timestamp else {return}
                        guard let img = self.profileImg else {return}
                        let date2 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timestamp2.seconds))
                        
                        let usermessages = driverMessages(image: img, text: message2, date: date2, isSender: false, driverid: senderid2)
                        self.messages.append(usermessages)
                        
                        self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
                            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.comments.count, section: 0)
                            self.messages.append(usermessages)
                            self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
                        }, completion: nil)
                        
                        }
                            
                     }
                 }
                
             }
         }
      }
```

***this is my code***

```
func getMessages(){
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}

        
        let firestore = Firestore.firestore()
        let doc = firestore.collection("طلبات قيد العمل").whereField("driverUid", isEqualTo: uid)
        doc.getDocuments { (query, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            }
            for document in query!.documents{
                let chatDoc = document.reference.collection("المحادثات")

                chatDoc.addSnapshotListener { (querysnap, err) in
                    if err != nil {
                        print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                    }
                    self.messages = []
                    for snap in querysnap!.documents{
                    
                    let data = snap.data()
                    guard let message = data["message"] as? String else {return}
                    guard let senderid = data["senderID"] as? String else {return}
                    guard let timestamp = data["date"] as? Timestamp else {return}
                    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timestamp.seconds))
                    if senderid == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
                        let drivermessages = driverMessages(image: UIImage(), text: message, date: date, isSender: true, driverid: senderid)
                        self.messages.append(drivermessages)
                        
                    }else {
                        
                        guard let message2 = data["message"] as? String else {return}
                        guard let senderid2 = data["senderID"] as? String else {return}
                        guard let timestamp2 = data["date"] as? Timestamp else {return}
                        guard let img = self.profileImg else {return}
                        let date2 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timestamp2.seconds))
                        
                        let usermessages = driverMessages(image: img, text: message2, date: date2, isSender: false, driverid: senderid2)
                        self.messages.append(usermessages)
                        
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.collectionView.reloadData()
                            let item = self.messages.count - 1
                            let insertionIndexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
                            self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: insertionIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
                        }
                            
                     }
                 }
                
             }
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am very new to coding myself.
However it seems to me something that could help you would be to have an `.onSnapshot` listener looking for `change` of type `added`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentChange.Type

I found this article very helpful for the the CRUD application I am working on:

https://bezkoder.com/react-hooks-firestore/

Part of it shows how to listen for changes of various types.
I was able to implement that into my app to return only the added document rather than the entire collection, and then append that to my array.

```
   tutorialsRef.onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
    if (change.type === "added") {
      console.log("New tutorial: ", change.doc.data());
    }
    if (change.type === "modified") {
      console.log("Modified tutorial: ", change.doc.data());
    }
    if (change.type === "removed") {
      console.log("Removed tutorial: ", change.doc.data());
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: that's mean if I called this method on viewDidload that's mean it will not work until there is a new change happend `.added, .delete, .modified` ?? and it will not load any data ??

Comment: I will be honest, I don't understand exactly what you are doing. But for my app, I was able to have the `onSnapshot` listen for changes using `.docChanges()`. I think if I understand correctly, this returns an object that includes the type of change - `change.type` - the id of the document that changed - `change.doc.id` - and the full contents of the document - `change.doc.data()`. Then I checked if this doc.id was already in my state, and if not, I added the doc to my state object array. It could be helpful to you because the `.onSnapshot` only gets the changes to Firestore. ...I think.